# The definition of the resultant of two polynomials over a UFD

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

In the book *Principle in Algebraic Geometry* of Griffiths & Harris, I encountered the following definition of the resultant of two polynomials:

> If $R$ is a UFD and $u,v\in R[t]$ are relatively prime, then there exist relatively prime elements $\alpha,\beta\in R[t]$, $\gamma\neq 0\in R$, such that
> $$\alpha u+\beta v=\gamma.$$
> $\gamma$ is called the *resultant* of $u$ and $v$.

This definition seems strange to me, since I'm much more familiar with the definition of resultant [using determinants of the coefficients of two polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition). However, I tried to show how these definitions are equivalent with each other. It is clear that $\gamma\in (u,v)$, the ideal of $R[t]$ generated by $u$ and $v$. Then $(u,v)\cap R$ is non-empty and different from $(0)$. Why this must be true? And why $\gamma$ must be unique?

Hope someone can explain that to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(u,v)\cap R\neq0$ because you get $fu+gv=1$, $f,g\in \operatorname{Frac}(R)[t]$ then clear denominators of $f,g$.  $\gamma$ is not unique, but up to units of $R$.

Comment: Didn't expect the use of Gauss' Lemma... Thank you!